# Django Rest Framework authentication - how to implement custom decorator

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement TokenAuthentication using the Rest Framework, but it seems that I can't add my own custom decorators to my ViewSets because they are evaluated BEFORE the authentication.  Consider this:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden

def require_staff(View):
    def staffOnly(function):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff:
                return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return wrap

    View.dispatch = method_decorator(staffOnly)(View.dispatch)
    return View
```

When I try to implement this, it seems the decorator code fires first, so the authentication is never run.

```
@require_staff
class CustomerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Customer

    filter_class = CustomerFilter
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Since **request.user** is never set, introducing the decorator breaks authentication.

I think the issue is that Authentication is occuring the rest_frameworks dispatch() function and it is not clear to me how I could add additional (say) custom security if authentication is done that late in the game.

Am I missing something here, or what is the proper way to implement this customization?

Someone suggested using Permissions for this instead.  I assume they mean custom DRF Permissions, right?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is DRF permissions is here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions

DRF provides a built in permission that is similar to yours, called `IsAdminUser`

> The `IsAdminUser` permission class will deny permission to any user,
>   unless `user.is_staff` is `True` in which case permission will be allowed.
>
> This permission is suitable is you want your API to only be accessible
>   to a subset of trusted administrators.

To use this permission in a Class Based View:

`class ExampleView(APIView):
        permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)`

Now you have two options to do an extra check for `user.is_active`.

The first is override the `IsAdminUser` permission, like so:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsActiveAndAdminUser(permissions.IsAdminUser):
"""Only allow a user who is Admin and Active to view this endpoint. """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        is_admin = super(IsAdminAndActiveUser, self).has_permission(request, view)
        return request.user.is_active and is_admin
```

The second is to create an `IsActiveUser` permission, and chain them in your view.

`IsActiveUser` Permission:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsActiveUser(permissions.BasePermission):
""" Only Active Users have permission """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_active
```

Your new permission list in your class based view:

`class ExampleView(APIView):
        permission_classes = (IsActiveUser, IsAdminUser,)`